# C++ Stack Frame/Activation Record and 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, this, activation

This is my first post here, if I am messing something up I would appreciate any advice.
Does C++ implement an activation record? My experience with this has been largely with Java so I am unsure if it is the same for other languages.
If so, in C++ is it correct to say that 'this' is a pointer to the previous record on the activation stack?
For example:

```
...
class Example {
private:
    int num;
public:
    void setNum(int num) {
        this->num = num;
    }
...
```

So the activation stack would have an 'Example' object on the stack and then when the function 'setNum(...)' is called it would put that call on the activation stack. So 'this' would be of type Example* and would point to the 'Example' object that is on the stack before the function call. Is that correct?
Thanks all!

Comment: You are mixing terminologies. A "stack frame" is the current region of memory created for use by a function. The "activation-record" (function prologue) saves required callee saved registers, and the callers stack pointer as the current frame pointer so your program can restore the callee saved registers and knows where to transfer control on function return.  None of that applies to the `this` pointer of an object.

Comment: _"So `this` would point to the `Example` object that is on the stack before the function call?"_ No, generally, it's not correct. `this` would point to the actual object wherever it is. If it is on the heap, then `this` would point to this object that is on the heap.

Comment: Anyway, C++ has no concept of a _stack_. You need to look at the implementation details, such as a compiler or ABI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` only exists within a `class` or `struct`. It does not exists within a free function.

`this` points to the object whose member function is called.

In your case, `this` points to an instance of `Example` and thus the type is `Example*`

I don't know the term **ActivationRecord**. C++ doesn't know the concept of a function stack, that's just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is very stright in с++. `this` will be pointer to current object(instance of `class Example`). And if `setNum` can be called then you already have this object. You do not need this for setting value to any memeber.

```
class Example {
private:
    int num;
public:
    void setNum(int _num) {
        num = _num;
    }
};
```